# Tooltip is positioned in the bottom of the svg in d3.js

Tags: javascript, css, angular, d3.js

I have placed a tooltip on the d3 charts ( scatter plot, line chart etc ). Issue is they all are bottom aligned like in the image below. I need them to appear little above the circles. At first, I thought maybe I am using ngx-bootstrap tooltip so maybe bootstrap tooltip class overrides the one I am using in the charts but thats not even the case.

How to accomplish this?

[image]

Code :

```
 let div = d3
      .select(this.chartElem.nativeElement)
      .select(".linechart")
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 0)
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("background-color", "white")
      .style("border", "solid")
      .style("border-width", "1px")
      .style("border-radius", "5px")
      .style("padding", "10px");
  
 this.svgInner
        .selectAll(".svg-container")
        .data(this.data1)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "dot")
        .attr("fill", (d) => {
          if ((d.age - 10) * (d.age - 19) <= 0) {
            return "#042F5B ";
          }
          if ((d.age - 20) * (d.age - 29) <= 0) {
            return "#053E78 ";
          }
          if ((d.age - 30) * (d.age - 39) <= 0) {
            return "#074E95 ";
          }
          if ((d.age - 40) * (d.age - 49) <= 0) {
            return "#0964C0";
          }
          if ((d.age - 50) * (d.age - 59) <= 0) {
            return "#0E81F4 ";
          }
          if ((d.age - 50) * (d.age - 59) <= 0) {
            return "#4DA0F3";
          }
          if ((d.age - 60) * (d.age - 69) <= 0) {
            return "#77B4F1";
          }
        })
        .attr("data-xvalue", (d) => d.p1)
        .attr("data-yvalue", (d) => d.p2)
        .attr("cx", (d) => {
          return this.xScale(d.p1);
        })

        .attr("cy", (d) => this.yScale(d.p2))

        .attr("r", 4)
        .on("mouseover", (event, d: any) => {
          tooltip
            // started as 0!
            .html(
              "PC1: " +
                d.p1+
                "<br>" +
                "PC2: " +
                d.p2
            )
            /*   .style("left", d3.pointer(this)[0] + 90 + "px") // It is important to put the +90: other wise the tooltip is exactly where the point is an it creates a weird effect
            .style("top", d3.pointer(this)[1] + "px") */
            .transition()
            .duration(200) // ms
            .style("opacity", 0.9);
        })
        .on("mouseout", (event, d) => {
          tooltip
            .transition()
            .duration(300) // ms
            .style("opacity", 0); // don't care about position!
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event's `layerX` and `layerY` to position your tooltip:

```js
.on("mouseover", (event, d) => {
  tooltip
    .html(...)
    .style('left', event.layerX)
    .style('top', event.layerY)
    .transition()
    ...
})
```